# Is there a way to skip over reading empty cells in merged cells in Excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read these [cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVKm5.png) using openpyxl in Python. There are two merged cells called 'Name' and I am trying to create a for loop to read the cells but skip over cells that have the same content. To do this, I check each cell with its succeeding column or its succeeding row, if they are the same, I skip over them. The problem is only the rest of the cells in the merged cell are called 'None' so it compares 'None' with 'Name' and doesn't skip over the duplicate. The desired output is "Clear, Name" but instead I get "Clear, Name, Name". Is there a way to detect the duplicate even though it is a merged cell?

Here is my current approach:

```
    origName2 = sheet.cell(row=(rowNum+1), column=colNum).value
    origName1 = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=(colNum+1)).value
    origName = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=colNum).value


    if str(origName) == "None":
        pass
    elif str(origName) == str(origName1):
        pass
    elif str(origName) == str(origName2):
        pass
    else:
        commands.append(origName)
```

Comment: can provide us with something that you've tried?

Comment: Hi Anurag, I just edited my code into my original post.